# Multiple DomainSite: when one domain site admin login in Umbraco, he can't see other Domain Site user

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I have one use case in Umbraco. My project is Multidomain site (India, China, Greece). When I create a USER (India admin and group-adminIndia) from main administrator and in adminIndia group I give permission all along with user.

I did same thing with China and Greece admin. Now when I log in from India admin I can also disable other admin and vice versa.

This is the problem. My requirement is this: **when India admin logs in, he shouldn't be able to see admins from others groups**. Can anyone help with this issue?. Can I do it with Javascript or Jquery?

Check images: 1) Admin china group screen 2) admin india group 3)Login from indian admin now he can disable china admin. This is the problem. 4)Login from main admin . 5) content in umbraco backoffice

[image: Admin china group screen]
[image: admin india group]

[image: Login from indian admin now he can disable china admin.this is the problem.]

[image: Login from main admin]

[image: content page]

Comment: I guess you just have one Umbraco installation, right?

Comment: yes! in one umbraco there are multidomain (3) sites.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give permission to both groups to the Users section in addition to their respective content nodes root:

[image: Example for China group]

Comment: i did the same thing check images

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your issue. I tried that and if I log in as China Admin I can see the Indian Admin.

Comment: my requirement : when i login as china admin i CAN'T see the Indian Admin

Comment: Well, that's working for me on a new umbraco site so you must have an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Can you please go through This Document . and tell me where i am going wrong https://drive.google.com/open?id=17DSqP5dhyCZO8E61P3TbzeKUSVOgIMBf

Answer (score 1):

You should not give USER section access  permission to your indian , china etc admin While making group. you should handle by main admin.

[Remove User Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8tBU.png)

[image]

Comment: this is not possible! main admin(I) cant handle all of this.i have to deliver project to client with accessing User section.and my simple requirement is  : when i login as china admin i CAN'T see the Indian Admin.thats it no big deal. but  i don't know how to do in umbraco.